# How to use construct method in Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I want to override construct method in my model, however, when I try to use the construct method inside my model, it returns an error saying `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::construct()`

The purpose of using `__construct` method is that I want to use DB table dynamically.

What is the problem? How could avoid this error?

**Model**

```
class Custom extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id', 'ct'];

const UPDATED_AT = null;
const CREATED_AT = 'ct';

public function __construct(string $tableName = null, array $attributes = []) {

    $this->setTable($tableName);

    parent::construct($attributes);
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
$custom = new Custom($tableName);
$result = $custom->create($data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean to use `parent::__construct($attributes);` instead of `parent::construct($attributes);`.There's no `construct` method, like the error message said.